# Decimal Regex Constraint Matching (Four digits before optional decimal point and two after)

Tags: regex

I need to figure out how to make my regex allow match correctly each time I type a number/decimal point. I want to limit the number of digits before and after the decimal point, which isnt too hard but i cant figure out how to allow the decimal point to match as well.

```
1 - match
12 - match
1234 - match
12345 - wrong
1234. - match
1234.1 - match
1234.12 - match
1234.123 - wrong

Other matched numbers
12.12
1.0
123.99
```

Edit:

So I want a max of 4 numbers before the decimal place and two after. Also the decimal place is optional.

The tricky part is that I want it to fail if the fifth character isn't a decimal point.

Comment: You can escape . with a backslash: `\.` matches `.`

Comment: why would you match `1234.`? Also what have you tried?

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish because I am treating them as constraints so in order for them to type "1.23" they need to first type "1."

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish Also if they stop at 1234. then I will correct the field to 1234.00 when they leave the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your constraints better; I'm assuming you want a maximum of 4 before the dot and 2 after:

`/^\d{1,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/`

edit: I added beginning and end of string matchers. Should work as you want now

Comment: this answer doesn't work because when I type 1234000, I am still getting a match on the first four characters and I want it to fail if the fifth character isn't a decimal point.

Comment: This works great, i wasn't reading the test compiler correctly before. This is also very readable. Thx

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish correct. It's a trade-off between a more powerful (and complicated regex) or a simpler regex and some (very basic) input parsing. I'm in favour of parsing input so each number is on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help

```
r'^\d{1,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$'
```

As you must be aware, \d represents a digit, . for the decimal point and {min_required,max_required}. Be sure to test your regular expression prior to using them [here.](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: this answer doesn't work because when I type 12345, I am still getting a match on the first four characters and I want it to fail if the fifth character isn't a decimal point.

Comment: The syntax `{,2}` is less compatible with different regex flavors. Use `{0,2}` instead.

Comment: You literally copied my answer, twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to select only those words that consists of digits and satisfying your condition.

```
/(?<=^|\s)\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{0,2})?(?=\s|$)/g
```

Positive lookahead and lookbehind are used to make sure that a whitespace is around the number.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uH8fQ8/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/llUQMFLLJ0j4CDad)